# Can I configure apache to limit access to a directory only from my ssh connection?

Tags: ssh, apache-httpd

I have a virtual machine running a number of websites.  All users have access these via the external IP address of the machine. I am running Debian Stable on this machine.

I can access the machine via `ssh` and have organized it so I port forward my local `10080` port to `localhost:80` so I can connect my browser to localhost port `10080`/phpmyadmin and gain access to phpmyadmin.  My machine is on a `192.168.0.0/24` network

Trouble is, you can also access it via any of the external web sites - because Debian has placed it in the top level Apache config.

I would like to limit access to only connections via the `ssh` port.  But there doesn't appear to be the equivalent of a listen directive for a directory.

However there is Allow from IP_address. What IP address does apache think I connected on when I come over the `ssh` tunnel.

Comment: This seems like an overly complicated set up. Why didn't you just configure apache to `Listen` on port 10080 and create a default virtual host for that port that serves the phpMyAdmin application? If it's a security thing, you can just configure that virtualhost for SSL via `SSLEngine on`

Comment: You may look into `Allow/Deny` statements to only [allow connections that seem to be coming from localhost](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/access.html) (which should be how apache sees the remote user as connecting since the local `sshd` is doing the relay).

Comment: Allow/Deny did it, with 127.0.0.1  The connection appeared to be coming from its own local host

Comment: @bersch [*organised* isn't actually a typo.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/American_and_British_English_spelling_differences#-ise.2C_-ize_.28-isation.2C_-ization.29)

Comment: @n.st ah I see, thanks, wrong province, I'll take care of it next time. Although I consider if "organyse" would bye satisfactory for all. :-)

Comment: This is an apache configuration question, however if you didn't know that the request would appear to come from localhost, take a look in the apache logfile.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about restricting access via an apache configuration. However if you didn't know that the request would appear to come from localhost, make a request and take a look in the apache logfile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, this is relatively simple to solve.

You access your server with

```
 ssh -L 5580:localhost:80 www.servername.tld
```

and you access your phpmyadmin via

```
 http://localhost:5580/phpmyadmin/
```

> because Debian has placed it

If you would have M$, you can say this, but you have Debian, so you can change the defaults as you need. :-)

> However there is Allow from IP_address. What IP address does apache think I connected on when I come over the ssh tunnel.

The same as you have already used: `localhost`

Simplest solution here, you said it already

```
# /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf 
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
<Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>

  ...
  AllowOverride None
  Order deny,allow
  Deny from all
  Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

Another solution would be to listen on an additional port to have an exclusive access to phpmyadmin:

Files to change:

```
 # /etc/apache2/ports.conf
 Listen localhost:8880
```

and

```
# /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf 
<VirtualHost *:8880>
  ServerName localhost
  Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
  <Directory /usr/share/phpmyadmin>

     ...
     Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
  </Directory>    
</VirtualHost>
```

Eventually

```
 apache2ctl configtest
 apache2ctl restart
```

The redirection command

```
 ssh -L 5580:localhost:8880 www.servername.tld
```

and connect to

```
 http://localhost:5580/phpmyadmin/
```